# server only accept once and terminate

Tags: linux, server, wait

I'm learning Unix Network Programming in Chapter5, wait and waitpid functions. I test function wait. I run the server application firstly and then the client(repeat ./a.out several times). But the server can only accept the request one time and terminated. Errno is 4.

```
/* server.c
 *
 *  gcc server.c -o server
 *  ./server &     (run in background)
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sig_chld(int signum)        // SIGCHLD handler
{
    int stat;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = wait(&stat);
}

int main(void)
{
    int listenfd;
    int connfd; 
    struct sigaction act; 
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    pid_t pid;

    act.sa_handler = sig_chld;        // register SIGCHLD handler 
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0; 
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL);

    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    bzero(&addr, addrlen);            // fill server address 
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080); 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.10", &addr.sin_addr.s_addr); 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen); 
    listen(listenfd, 5); 

    while (1) {           // waiting for client request
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen); 
        if (connfd < 0) {
            printf("connect\n"); 
            break; 
        } 
        pid = fork(); 
        if (pid < 0) { 
            exit(-1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {           // child 
              close(listenfd); 
              write(connfd, "hello\n", 7); 
              exit(0); 
        }  
        else {                          // parent 
            close(connfd);
        }
    }
    return 0; 
} 



/* client.c 
 *
 *   gcc client.c
 *   ./a.out (repeat several times)
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    int cliefd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    socklen_t addrlen;

    addrlen = sizeof(servaddr);
    bzero(&servaddr, addrlen);          // fill server address
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.10", &servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    cliefd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connect(cliefd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, addrlen) < 0) {
        printf("error: %d\n", errno);
        exit(-1);
    }
    read(cliefd, buf, MAXLINE);
    fputs(buf, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also supplement your network learning with [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It is an excellent reference/tutorial for network programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errno` value 4 is `EINTR`. This indicates that a system call was interrupted. In this case, the `SIGCHLD` is interrupting the `accept` system call. Keep reading further in that chapter. Below is a quote from it which specifically points that out for this particular example code:

> 4. Since the signal was caught by the parent while the parent was blocked in a slow system call (accept), the kernel causes `accept` to return an error of `EINTR` (interrupted system call). The parent does not handle this error so it aborts.
>
> The purpose of this example is to show that when writing network programs that catch signals, we must be cognizant of interrupted system calls, and we must handle them.

It goes on further to explain how the signal can be set up to automatically restart interrupted system calls. In summary, set the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `act.sa_flags` field:

```
act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
```

Comment: And so they say "...and now for the rest of the story..." Seems you have the same book and have read the rest of the story. That's worth something.